# Calling a abstract method from a callback inside a abstract class

Tags: java, undertow

I am using undertow as my HTTP library and want to verify the JWT token and HTTP method of every request. I don't want to implement the verification in every `HttpHandler`. Is this the right way to do it?

**Handler.java**

```
public abstract class Handler implements HttpHandler {

    private HttpString[] methods;

    Handler(HttpString... methods) {
        this.methods = methods;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange httpServerExchange) throws Exception {
        // verifying HTTP method
        boolean verified = false;
        for (HttpString method : methods) {
            if (httpServerExchange.getRequestMethod().equals(method)) {
                verified = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!verified) {
            // return http 405, cause: invalid HTTP method
            httpServerExchange.setStatusCode(StatusCodes.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
            httpServerExchange.getResponseSender().send(Variables.Response.EMPTY);
        }

    // verifying JWT token
    String jwt = httpServerExchange.getRequestHeaders().get("jwt", 0);
    JWT.verifyToken(jwt)
            .addListener(token -> {
                if (token != null) {
                    handleVerifiedRequest(httpServerExchange, token);
                } else {
                    // return http 400, cause: JWT invalid
                    httpServerExchange.setStatusCode(StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED);
                    httpServerExchange.getResponseSender().send(Variables.Errors.INVALID_JWT);
                }
            });
    }

    public abstract void handleVerifiedRequest(HttpServerExchange httpServerExchange, String Token);
}
```

**HelloHandler.java**

```
public class HelloHandler extends Handler {

    public HelloHandler(HttpString... methods) {
        super(methods);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleVerifiedRequest(HttpServerExchange httpServerExchange, String Token) {
        // .. do something
    }
}
```

Comment: doesnt look like there is anything wrong with your solution.

Comment: @aiguy Cool, thanks! It's the first time Implemented a abstract class.. :D

Comment: Using this approach will prevent you to chain other handlers. I would suggest that you stick with the Undertow API (HttpHandler and exchange Attachments.) I can elaborate in an actual answer if you are interested.

Comment: @aramaki I'm very interested, I will highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more reusable and recommended approach would be to stick with the Undertow HttpHandler API and to chain handlers together.

First, as you already proposed, your JWT authentication handler, checking for an incoming token in the request:

```
public class JwtAuthHandler implements HttpHandler {

  AttachmentKey<JwtToken> JWT_TOKEN = AttachmentKey.create(JwtToken.class);

  private final HttpHandler next;
  public JwtAuthHandler(HttpHandler next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  @Override
  public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
    ...
    JWT.verifyToken(jwt)
        .addListener(token -> {
          if (token != null) {
            exchange.putAttachment(JWT_TOKEN, token);
            next.handleRequest(exchange);
          } else {
            // return http 400, cause: JWT invalid
            httpServerExchange.setStatusCode(StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED);
            httpServerExchange.getResponseSender().send(Variables.Errors.INVALID_JWT);
          }
        });
  }
}
```

One difference though, it simply implements the HttpHandler interface and expects a **next** HttpHandler to call in case of success. Before calling the **handleRequest** method on the next handler, note the line to add the current valid token as an exchange attachment. Attachments are a way to pass data between handlers.

Then, your **HelloHandler** simply expects a JwtToken from the exchange attachments (note that this is just a guess, I don't know what JWT library do you use, this is simply the type of the **token** variable in your example.)

```
public class HelloHandler implements HttpHandler {

  @Override
  public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
    JwtToken token = exchange.getAttachment(JWT_TOKEN);
    ...
  }
}
```

This handler will only be called if the request authentication is successful.

As you probably know, handlers are meant to be chained together:

```
Undertow.builder()
    .addHttpListener(8080, "0.0.0.0")
    .setHandler(new JwtAuthHandler(new HelloHandler()))
    .build().start();
```

If you stick with the HttpHandler API, you can easily integrate and use existing handlers that Undertow provides, look [here](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/tree/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/server/handlers).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will force a subclass to implement `handleVerifiedRequest` but will also allow someone to reimplement `handleRequest` to circumvent your verification.  To prevent a subclass from doing so, add the `final` keyword to the original method in your abstract class.

```
public abstract class Handler implements HttpHandler {
    // ... //

    @Override
    public final void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange httpServerExchange) throws Exception {
       // ... your verification code ... //
    }

    public abstract void handleVerifiedRequest(HttpServerExchange httpServerExchange, String Token);
}
```